# JQuery autocomplete: display several attributes of a same JSON object in one field

Tags: jquery, json, rest, autocomplete

I'm using for the first time the jquery autocomplete-plugin with data coming from an API Rest. I want the user of the app to select a city (from the suggestions displayed). Additional fields matching with the selected city (like region, departement and so on) are filled automatically based on the JSON object returned by the autocomplete.

So far, everything works perfectly. 
Here the code (to make the exemple clearer, I hardcoded the data):

```
$(function () {

var data =  [
{
    "codeRegion": "93",
    "codeDepartement": "13",
    "zipCodes": [
        "13001",
        "13002",
        "13003",
        "13004",
        "13005",
        "13006",
        "13007",
        "13008",
        "13009",
        "13010",
        "13011",
        "13012",
        "13013",
        "13014",
        "13015",
        "13016"
    ],
    "nom": "Marseille",
    "code": "13055",
    "_score": 0.515005204471824,
    "departement": {
        "code": "13",
        "nom": "Bouches-du-Rhône"
    },
    "region": {
        "code": "93",
        "nom": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
    }
},
{
    "codeRegion": "76",
    "codeDepartement": "32",
    "zipCodes": [
        "32170"
    ],
    "nom": "Marseillan",
    "code": "32238",
    "_score": 0.4956346463216245,
    "departement": {
        "code": "32",
        "nom": "Gers"
    },
    "region": {
        "code": "76",
        "nom": "Occitanie"
    }
},
{
    "codeRegion": "76",
    "codeDepartement": "34",
    "zipCodes": [
        "34340"
    ],
    "nom": "Marseillan",
    "code": "34150",
    "_score": 0.4956346463216245,
    "departement": {
        "code": "34",
        "nom": "Hérault"
    },
    "region": {
        "code": "76",
        "nom": "Occitanie"
    }
},
{
    "codeRegion": "76",
    "codeDepartement": "65",
    "zipCodes": [
        "65350"
    ],
    "nom": "Marseillan",
    "code": "65301",
    "_score": 0.4956346463216245,
    "departement": {
        "code": "65",
        "nom": "Hautes-Pyrénées"
    },
    "region": {
        "code": "76",
        "nom": "Occitanie"
    }
},
]

    $("#cityNameInput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {

           response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value.nom,
                            value: value.nom,
                            region: value.region,
                            departementName: value.departement.nom,
                            code: value.departement.code
                        }
                    }));
                },



        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#cityNameInput").val(ui.item.nom);
                      return false;
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#cityNameInput").val(ui.item.nom);
            $("#region").val(ui.item.region.nom);
            $("#departementName").val(ui.item.departementName);
            $("#departementId").val(ui.item.code);
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

I have only one probleme: 
- as you see different cities may have the same name (in this exemple there are 2 "Marseillan") 
- further: big cities like "Marseille" are subdivised in different districts, each of them having its own zip code.

So what I'd like to do, is to have in the autocomplete-suggestions-list not only the name of the cities displayed, but also additionnal information like the zipcode. So that every proposal is very unique.

I've tried different things but couldnt make it work. 
Could someone help me on this matter?

Here the link on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cg285qwp/

Comment: Do you wanted to see like this: **Marseille: zip-13** In drop-down list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in autocomplete source

```
source: function (request, response) {

           response($.map(data, function (value, key) { 
           var response_array = [];
             $.each(value.zipCodes,function()
             {
                response_array.push(
                  {
                    label: value.nom+" zip:"+this,
                    value: value.nom,
                    region: value.region,
                    departementName: value.departement.nom,
                    code: value.departement.code
                  }
                            );
                            });
            return response_array;
      }));
 },
```

Here the label is concatenated with zip code please check

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What I'd like to see: "Marseille 13001", "Marseille 13002"... 13001 and 13002 being one of the possible zip codes for the city Marseille. What you suggested doesn't work because "value.code" refers to another code, not to the ZIP codes. One city can have many zip codes and they are stored in a nested array (see the structure of the JSON object in my post).

Comment: Do you want all records from zip? Its to many do you want all records for zip?

Comment: The user should make a choice among the different zip, because at the end for my business logic i will need one city with only one zip. In order to achieve that I was hopping to have in the suggestion list for the autocomplete field each time ( city_name + 1 zip). So if a same city has 3 different zip codes, it should appear 3 times in the suggestion list, each time with a different zip code. If this is not possible or too complicated, another option could be to have the user first choose a city with autocomplete and then populate all the matching zip codes in a html select form.

Comment: @JulienBerthoud I have updated the code please check.